I have result set R. event A and event B what is (A ∩ B)’?
I have result set R. event A and event B what is (A ∩ B)’?
I have asked the question in several places and i get contradicting or different answers. What i know based on De Morgan's law is that (A ∩ B)' = A' U B'
Let me give an example
R = {all employable people}
Event A = {all un-employed}
Event B = {All looking for a job}
what is (A ∩ B)'?
My answer is that (A ∩ B)' = A' U B' = {only Employed, only not looking for a job, employed and not looking for a job}. In set notation this would be (A'\B') U (B'\A') U (A'∩ B') but i get that this is not the correct answer. where did i get it wrong?
Thanks!

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see How can I format mathematics here? and the MathJax tutorial.

For $\cup$ write \cup and for $\cap$ write \cap, of course inside $...$ as all formulas should be.

What does $R$ have to do with this problem? Also, what are you asked to provide? Are you looking for an interpretation in words? As it is worded, it looks like you are asking for the definition of set intersection.
